# how to change background color of li elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the color of `<li>` elements on hover. But the problem is that when I hover on (in following example) `fig li` both the color getting changed on fig it is yellow and on orange `parent li`.
and second when I hover on fig then pear then date and then orange no event gor fired and no color changes.

HTML:

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="no-list-style hover-brown">orange
            <ul>
                <li class="hover-yellow">date</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">pear</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">fig</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".hover-brown").hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).not(".hover-yellow").css("background","brown");
  }, function() {
    $( this ).not(".hover-yellow").css("background","white");
  }
);

$(".hover-yellow").hover(
  function() {
$(".hover-brown").not(".hover-yellow").css("background","white");
    $( this ).css("background","yellow");
  }, function() {
     $( this ).css("background","white");
  }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4q7uf14h/

Comment: what is your question? and desired output.

Comment: Please check the grammar of your question. Your desired output is unclear.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you wanted:

```
ul>li>ul>li:hover{
    background-color: yellow;

    transition: background-color 1s;
}

.hover-brown:hover{
    background-color: brown;
    transition: background-color 0.4s;
}
```

[Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4q7uf14h/2/)

Comment: I could do it and i have tried it too but I want to change the background color of orange too on hover, sorry but your answer is no doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the first `<li>` tag to display brown with out the whole `<ul>` turning brown. If so please try this. End the `<li>` tag after orange.

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="no-list-style hover-brown">orange</li>
            <ul>
                <li class="hover-yellow">date</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">pear</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">fig</li>
            </ul>

    </ul>
</div>


$(".hover-brown").hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).not(".hover-yellow").css("background","brown");
  }, function() {
    $( this ).not(".hover-yellow").css("background","white");
  }
);

$(".hover-yellow").hover(
  function() {
$(".hover-brown").not(".hover-yellow").css("background","white");
    $( this ).css("background","yellow");
  }, function() {
     $( this ).css("background","white");
  }
);
```

[jsfiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/KnowledgeGuard/4q7uf14h/11/)

**Edit:**

Your Code:

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="no-list-style hover-brown">orange
            <ul>
                <li class="hover-yellow">date</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">pear</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">fig</li>
            </ul>
        </li> //Remove and place after the word orange
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Please try this:**

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="no-list-style"><span class="span-hover">orange</span>
            <ul>
                <li class="hover-yellow">date</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">pear</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">fig</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


    $(".span-hover").hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).not(".hover-yellow").css("background","brown");
  }, function() {
    $( this ).not(".hover-yellow").css("background","white");
  }
);

$(".hover-yellow").hover(
  function() {
$(".span-hover").not(".hover-yellow").css("background","white");
    $( this ).css("background","yellow");
  }, function() {
     $( this ).css("background","white");
  }
);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KnowledgeGuard/4q7uf14h/15/)

**And if you want to keep it uniform use this...**

```
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="no-list-style"><span class="span-hover">orange</span>
            <ul>
                <li ><span class="span-hover-yellow">date</span></li>
                <li ><span class="span-hover-yellow">pear</span></li>
                <li ><span class="span-hover-yellow">fig</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


$(".span-hover").hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).not(".span-hover-yellow").css("background","brown");
  }, function() {
    $( this ).not(".span-hover-yellow").css("background","white");
  }
);

$(".span-hover-yellow").hover(
  function() {
$(".span-hover").not(".span-hover-yellow").css("background","white");
    $( this ).css("background","yellow");
  }, function() {
     $( this ).css("background","white");
  }
);
```

Comment: You where ending the first <li> tag after the <ul> group. I ended the </li> right after the word orange.

Comment: But it was not by mistake, it was my requirement. Cant' you give the solution using that format?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS to format it?

```
li.hover-brown:hover {color:brown;}
li.hover-brown li:hover {color:yellow;}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried with css you can check it out

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4q7uf14h/3/)

```css
#tree ul li.hover-brown:hover{
    background-color: brown;
}
li.hover-brown .hover-yellow:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="no-list-style hover-brown">orange
            <ul>
                <li class="hover-yellow">date</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">pear</li>
                <li class="hover-yellow">fig</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```